# Как скомпилить C++ проект

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, makefile, g++

Очень нужна dll'ка получаемая при сборке одного из проектов (любого) в данном репозитории: 
http://sourceforge.net/p/zint/code/ci/master/tree/

В указанном репозитории, как я понял, несколько вариантов: для qt, VC++ и, я так полагаю, для C++ в GCC. Есть варианты создающие dll и варианты создающие десктопную программу использующую данную dll. Меня интересует именно dll...

Вот только проблема в том, что я ни с чем вышеперечисленным ране не работал на уровне достаточном для того, чтобы уметь собрать проект из файлов представленных в репозитории. 
Проект для VC++ у меня в 15-ой студии "с наскока" не собрался, ругается на отсутствие: Не удается открыть файл включение: png.h. Которого в директории проекта не наблюдается. В идеале хотелось бы конечно получить рабочую dll'ку именно в VS. Но если не выйдет, то любой другой вариант так же приемлем.
Qtшный проект так же ругается (не могу сказать на что именно, в поле вывода абракадабра какая-то...)

Вопрос: Какую последовательность действий мне нужно совершить чтобы скомпилировать один из представленных в репозитории проектов создающий dll библиотеку.

PS: Если кто-то сам скомпилит и кинет ссылку на zint.dll я конечно тоже буду признателен, но всё же хотелось бы знать как это делается.

Comment: Вобщем на qt или при сборке с помощью CMake + MinGW тоже вылазит ошибка отцутствия png.h. Как с ней разобраться не ясно...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Сборка `zint` с поддержкой PNG***

Сборку будем производить в некотором каталоге `%BUILD_ROOT%`. Везде в дальнейшем разделителем каталогов должна быть прямая дробная черта (`/`). При использовании обратной  (`\`) возможны ошибки сборки.

Для сборки в данном случае использовались `CMake` версии 3.3.2 и `MinGW-builds` версии 5.2.0rev0.

1. Сборка библиотеки `zlib` (использовалась версия 1.2.8).

Скачиваем архив исходников `zlib` и распаковываем его в каталог `%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib`. Далее собираем:

```
cd /d %BUILD_ROOT%
mkdir zlib-build
cd zlib-build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out ../zlib
cmake --build .
mingw32-make install
```

После этого в каталоге `%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out` будет скомпилированная библиотека `zlib`.

2. Сборка библиотеки `libpng` (использовалась версия 1.6.19).

Скачиваем архив исходников `libpng` и распаковываем его в каталог `%BUILD_ROOT%/libpng`. Собираем:

```
cd /d %BUILD_ROOT%
mkdir libpng-build
cd libpng-build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%BUILD_ROOT%/libpng-out -DZLIB_LIBRARY=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out/lib/libzlib.dll.a -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out/include ../libpng
cmake --build .
mingw32-make install
```

Предупреждения `CMake` игнорируем. После этого в каталоге `%BUILD_ROOT%/libpng-out` будет скомпилированная библиотека `libpng`.

3. Сборка библиотеки `zint` (использовалась версия 2.4.3).

Скачиваем архив исходников `zint` и распаковываем его в каталог `%BUILD_ROOT%/zint`. Файл `CMakeLists.txt` то ли не подходит для новых версий `CMake`, то ли в нём изначально ошибка, но в любом случае при сборке возникает ошибка, связанная с невозможностью найти файл `png.h`. Для исправления ошибки нужно этот файл немного подредактировать, а именно, в 14-й строке заменить `${PNG_INCLUDES}` на `${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS}`. Теперь можно собирать:

```
cd /d %BUILD_ROOT%
mkdir zint-build
cd zint-build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%BUILD_ROOT%/zint-out -DZLIB_LIBRARY=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out/lib/libzlib.dll.a -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out/include -DPNG_LIBRARY=%BUILD_ROOT%/libpng-out/lib/libpng.dll.a -DPNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR=%BUILD_ROOT%/libpng-out/include ../zint
cmake --build .
mingw32-make install
```

Предупреждения при сборке игнорируем. После выполнения всех шагов в каталоге `%BUILD_ROOT%/zint-out` будет требуемая библиотека `libzint.dll`.

4. Сборка без зависимостей.

Полученная `libzint.dll` имеет в зависимостях `libpng16.dll`, а та, в свою очередь, `libzlib.dll`. Кроме того, все эти библиотеки зависят от `libgcc*.dll`. Чтобы убрать все эти зависимости и сделать сборку (почти) полностью независимой, можно сделать следующее.

Определяем две переменных:

```
set CFLAGS=-static
set CXXFLAGS=%CFLAGS%
```

Эти переменные уберут зависимость библиотек от `libgcc*.dll`.

Чтобы убрать зависимость `libpng.dll` от `zlib.dll`, исправим один параметр при запуске `cmake`:

```
-DZLIB_LIBRARY=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out/lib/libzlibstatic.a
```

А чтобы убрать зависимость `libzint.dll` от `libpng16.dll` и `libzlib.dll`, нужно у `cmake` исправить два параметра:

```
-DZLIB_LIBRARY=%BUILD_ROOT%/zlib-out/lib/libzlibstatic.a
-DPNG_LIBRARY=%BUILD_ROOT%/libpng-out/lib/libpng.a
```

Готово! Полученная библиотека зависит только от `kernel32.dll` и `msvcrt.dll`.

Comment: Зачем 2 ответа? Вы либо слейте их, либо удалите один.

Comment: Всё собралось. Спасибо!