# Как добавить libpng в проект на Golang?

Tags: c, golang

Нужно подключить [пакет](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo) к проекту на Go.

Скомпилировал zlib затем libpng пользуясь [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469893/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

При команде *go get github.com/go-vgo/robotgo* выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
In file included from ./bitmap/../base/io_c.h:4:0,
             from ./bitmap/goBitmap.h:25,
             from ..\github.com\go-vgo\robotgo\robotgo.go:26:
 ./bitmap/../base/png_io_c.h:4:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or     directory
 #include <png.h>
```

Т.е. libpng он так и не видит. Нашел [похожую ситуацию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954719/png-h-not-found-in-mac-os-x-mavericks), но для os x

Вопрос: как подключать подобные пакеты в Golang? как показать *go get* что *libpng* существует?

Comment: Видимо, нужно выкачать libpng-dev

Comment: Что это даст? Он ругается на отсутствие файла, а не на его корректность.

Comment: А не пробовали положить в папку `./bitmap/../base/` все заголовочники libpng?